# Need to know how to start some GUI programs from terminal to use XMoand

Tags: command-line, gui, xmonad

I'm training myself to use XMONAD or something of the sort, but in order to do that, I need to know, from terminal, how to open the following programs:

1. Bluefish Editor
2. Settings (I'm using Ubuntu but will install XMONAD ENV.)
3. Ubuntu Software Center
4. View time

Comment: Do you only have a terminal (e.g. are you logging in through Putty from a Windows machine), or are you "at the computer" and having a GUI desktop as well? Which version of Ubuntu (assuming you are running Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?:

```
$ bluefish &
$ software-center &
$ unity-control-center &
```

and one of

```
$ date
$ cal 
$ xclock &
```

In practice, some programms write out some or many warning messages to stdout or stderr, which may clutter the terminal too much to use one terminal running multiple background programs, because you may see lots of mixed-up output, which you did not want to see in the first place.

So, if you had run a programm, it was writing errors and warnings (often in some subcomponent unknown to the programs author), but did work well enough, so you will not need the output actually use it, it makes sense to discard all output, from both output streams:

```
$ software-center >/dev/null 2&>1 &
```

If you may want to close the starting shell while the programms are still running in background, you could disown them from the shells job control, or use `nohup` to prevent the signal HUP ("hangup"), that would trigger the termination, from reaching the programm.

```
$ nohup xclock >/dev/null 2&>1 &
```